# Anti-concentration of polynomials on Haar measure

Tags: pr.probability, haar-measure

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ follow the Haar measure (i.e. uniformly distributed over the unit sphere), and $P$ be a degree-$d$ polynomial such that $\mathrm{Var}[P(X)]=1$. Are there constants $c(n,d)>0$ and $c'(n,d)$ such that
$$\Pr[|P(X)|\leq\varepsilon]\leq c'(n,d)\cdot\varepsilon^{c(n,d)}$$
holds for every $\varepsilon\geq 0$?

When $X$ consists of independent random variables, I'm aware of results that provide the above bound, and the constants even depend only on $d$ (for instance the Carbery-Wright inequality when $X$ follows the Gaussian distribution). On the other hand, when $P$ is homogeneous, we can reduce it to the Gaussian case as $X=G/\|G\|_2$ where $G$ is Gaussian and $\|G\|_2^2$ follows $\chi^2(n)$ distribution, and a tail bound on the later will introduce dependence on $n$ to $c'(n,d)$.

However, in the general case when $P$ is not homogeneous, are there any tools to prove such anti-concentration bounds?

I would also like to note that in the actual problem I'm studying, $X$ follows the Haar measure on unitary group, but I think the unit sphere case would be a good starting point. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly too long for a comment, and so I'm posting it as an answer.

It doesn't seem to me like there is a simple "hack" to translate Carbery-Wright to this setting.  The [original proof of Carbery-Wright](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/mrl/content/vols/0008/0003/a001/) is fairly geometric and so doesn't translate nicely to settings like uniform on the unit sphere.  However, what you seek is much weaker than what Carbery-Wright guarantees, in that you don't care about the optimal power on $\varepsilon$.  For this kind of a statement, there are more combinatorial approaches to anti-concentration.  In particular, one way to prove anti-concentration for non-linear functions is to use a "decoupling" approach.  For instance, Shachar Lovett has a nice proof of a weaker version of Carbery-Wright in this line (you can download the pdf of his proof [here](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2010/182/download/)).  It seems to me that something like this approach should be plausible for your case.  The main idea is that it converts a non-linear anti-concentration statement into a linear one.  Even more simply in your case, all you need is to convert a non-homogeneous anti-concentration statement into a homogeneous one.  Claims 3.2 and 3.3 in Lovett's paper do this kind of work, which it seems to me should be fairly analogous in your setting.

Comment: Thanks! I've actually managed to prove the statement even in the general setting (where the variables are entries of Haar-random unitary matrices), and the proof is indeed similar in essence with Lovett's proof. I will post it here once I find time.